# How can i stop CSS Grid cells from expanding due to text content?

Tags: css, web, flexbox, css-grid, responsive

SO i've attached a screenshot, i want my content cells to stop expanding past 600px in height because of the text when the screen is shrunk resulting in the odd design view. Instead i would like the text to either change to a smaller size or change to a scrolling behavior.

My Relevant CSS code.

```
.chars{
    padding: 100px;
    padding-top: 32px;
    margin-bottom: 32px;
    display:grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
    grid-auto-flow: dense;
    row-gap: 24px;
    border-top: 1px solid rgb(168, 168, 168);
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(168, 168, 168);
    transition: all 0.5s;
    min-width: 400px;
    min-height: 600px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

/* Setting all images of characters to fit in their cells. */
.chars img{
    width:400px;
    height:auto;
    border-radius: 3%;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.chars img:hover{
    width: 413px;
    height: auto;
}

.char1-img, .char3-img, .char5-img{
    grid-area: auto/1/auto/1;
    padding-top: 12px;
    padding-bottom: 12px;
}

.char1-content,.char3-content,.char5-content{
    grid-area: auto/2/auto/ -1;
    align-self: center;
    justify-self: center;

    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 22px
}

.char2-img,.char4-img,.char6-img{
    grid-area: auto/3/auto/3;
    padding-top: 12px;
    padding-bottom: 12px;
}

.char2-content,.char4-content,.char6-content{
    grid-area: auto/1/auto/ span 2;

    padding-top: 12px;
    padding-bottom: 12px;

    align-self: center;
    justify-self: center;

    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 22px
}

.char1-content p,
.char2-content p,
.char3-content p,
.char4-content p,
.char5-content p,
.char6-content p
{
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(235, 235, 235, 0), rgba(228, 228, 228, 0.8));
    padding-top: 32px;
    padding-left: 150px;
    padding-right: 150px;
    padding-bottom: 32px;
    
    border-radius: 1%;

    color:grey;
}

.char1-content h1,
.char3-content h1,
.char4-content h1,
.char5-content h1,
.char2-content h1,
.char6-content h1
{
    text-align: center;
}
```

HTML Code

```
<section class="chars">
            <div class="char1-img">
                <img src="./images/Leona.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="char1-content">
                <h1>The Creed of Face Swappers</h1>

                <p>
                    Leon Harper or rather Leona Harper is part of a creed of Assassins and spies who have the uncanny
                    ability to morph into any face they desire so as long as it is of the same gender and once they are
                    in
                    contact of it with the intent of morphing, Leona however is special even among her peers due to her
                    ability to not only swap faces but also into one of any man or woman this has undoubtedly led her to
                    be
                    one of the most proficient and competent among the rest despite being a new recruit placing her in
                    high
                    regards for the Elders in the Creed.
                    Much to the confusion surrounding her actual gender she has occasionally put out that she prefers to
                    spend most of her time as a woman and to be addressed as Leona rather than her male counterpart
                    "Leon".
                    Whatever the case may be no one can deny her stunningly enchanting appearance regardless of what she
                    chooses to go by.
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="char2-img">
                <img src="./images/Elizabeth.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="char2-content">
                <h1>Flames Of The Old World</h1>

                <p>
                    Elizabeth Burnley, a once-promising doctor, scientist, and scholar in a world where those
                    professions are distant memories. Raised in a post-apocalyptic realm ravaged by a relentless virus,
                    Elizabeth's life took a tragic turn when she lost her father to the very disease he fought to cure.
                    As she now navigates a harsh existence within a hidden vault, her journey as a doctor accompanying
                    search parties outside takes an unexpected turn, challenging her to adapt and survive in a world
                    where danger and mystery lurk at every corner.
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="char3-img">
                <img src="./images/abiha-al-farsi.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="char3-content">
                <h1>Abiha-al-Farsi</h1>

                <p>
                    "But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing pleasure and praising pain was
                    born and I will give you a complete account of the system, and expound the actual teachings of the
                    great explorer of the truth, the master-builder of human happiness. No one rejects, dislikes, or
                    avoids pleasure itself, because it is pleasure, but because those who do not know how to pursue
                    pleasure rationally encounter consequences that are extremely painful. Nor again is there anyone who
                    loves or pursues or desires to obtain pain of itself, because it is pain, but because occasionally
                    circumstances occur in which toil and pain can procure him some great pleasure. To take a trivial
                    example, which of us ever undertakes laborious physical exercise, except to obtain some advantage
                    from it? But who has any right to find fault with a man who chooses to enjoy a pleasure that has no
                    annoying consequences, or one who avoids a pain that produces no resultant pleasure?"
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="char4-img">
                <img src="./images/katrya.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="char4-content">
                <h1>The Ukranian Civil War</h1>

                <p>
                    "But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing pleasure and praising pain was
                    born and I will give you a complete account of the system, and expound the actual teachings of the
                    great explorer of the truth, the master-builder of human happiness. No one rejects, dislikes, or
                    avoids pleasure itself, because it is pleasure, but because those who do not know how to pursue
                    pleasure rationally encounter consequences that are extremely painful. Nor again is there anyone who
                    loves or pursues or desires to obtain pain of itself, because it is pain, but because occasionally
                    circumstances occur in which toil and pain can procure him some great pleasure. To take a trivial
                    example, which of us ever undertakes laborious physical exercise, except to obtain some advantage
                    from it? But who has any right to find fault with a man who chooses to enjoy a pleasure that has no
                    annoying consequences, or one who avoids a pain that produces no resultant pleasure?"
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="char5-img">
                <img src="./images/1.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="char5-content">
                <h1>Broken Dreams</h1>

                <p>
                    "But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing pleasure and praising pain was
                    born and I will give you a complete account of the system, and expound the actual teachings of the
                    great explorer of the truth, the master-builder of human happiness. No one rejects, dislikes, or
                    avoids pleasure itself, because it is pleasure, but because those who do not know how to pursue
                    pleasure rationally encounter consequences that are extremely painful. Nor again is there anyone who
                    loves or pursues or desires to obtain pain of itself, because it is pain, but because occasionally
                    circumstances occur in which toil and pain can procure him some great pleasure. To take a trivial
                    example, which of us ever undertakes laborious physical exercise, except to obtain some advantage
                    from it? But who has any right to find fault with a man who chooses to enjoy a pleasure that has no
                    annoying consequences, or one who avoids a pain that produces no resultant pleasure?"
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="char6-img">
                <img src="./images/9.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="char6-content">
                <h1>Blood Pact</h1>

                <p>
                    "But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing pleasure and praising pain was
                    born and I will give you a complete account of the system, and expound the actual teachings of the
                    great explorer of the truth, the master-builder of human happiness. No one rejects, dislikes, or
                    avoids pleasure itself, because it is pleasure, but because those who do not know how to pursue
                    pleasure rationally encounter consequences that are extremely painful. Nor again is there anyone who
                    loves or pursues or desires to obtain pain of itself, because it is pain, but because occasionally
                    circumstances occur in which toil and pain can procure him some great pleasure. To take a trivial
                    example, which of us ever undertakes laborious physical exercise, except to obtain some advantage
                    from it? But who has any right to find fault with a man who chooses to enjoy a pleasure that has no
                    annoying consequences, or one who avoids a pain that produces no resultant pleasure?"
                </p>
            </div>
        </section>
```

[image]

I've used overflow, min max heigh/width but doesn't work.

Comment: Would [grid-auto-flow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-auto-flow) help? Could you remove the extra code from your [mcve] please? There seems to be a lot of code that's unrelated to the problem.

Comment: I've tried that, didn't work. but the solution below gave me what i was looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your p tag selector add:

```
max-height: 600px;
overflow-y: auto;
```

Comment: This worked, more what i was looking for thanks! are there any other ways of achieving more or less the same effect?

Comment: You can technically control the parent grid row height through grid-template-rows but I think the p tag (or whatever element that would wrap the text) is the simplest option.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template-rows